# Numbers $9a+4$ and $2a+1$ are relative primes for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the positive integers of the form $9a+4$ and $2a+1$ with  $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ are relative primes, i.e, show that $\gcd(9a+4, 2a+1)=1$

Comment: Hint: try Euclid's algorithm for calculating the gcd. When you divide $9a+4$ by $2a+1$, the remainder is ... In the next step ... So what did you try? What went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $$9(2a+1) - 2(9a +4)=1 $$

So their gcd is a factor of $1$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(9a+4)=4 \cdot (2a+1)+a$. So, the g.c.d in question reduces to g.c.d of $(2a+1,a)$